# Set Textbox Value in opened Modal using javascript Dynamically

Tags: javascript, twig, bootstrap-modal, symfony

On button click open Model like this

```
<a href="#edit-venue" class="btn green editButton" data-toggle="modal" data-id="2" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit"><i class="icon-note"></i></a>
```

<kbd>Modal</kbd>

```
<div id="edit-venue" class="modal fade portlet" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="editVenue" method="post">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Venue Detail</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Venue12</b></label>
                                                        <div class="control-label col-sm-9 text-left">
                                                            <input id="venue" name="venue" class="form-control venue_name" placeholder="Enter venue" type="text">
                                                            <span class="error"></span>

                                                            <span class="error"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><b>Room/Stage</b></label>
                                                        <div class="control-label col-sm-9 text-left">
                                                            <input id="roomStage" name="roomStage" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter room/stage" type="text">
                                                            <span class="error"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn red">Cancel</button>
                                                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn green btn_save">Save</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

When I click on button open modal, I'd like to on click button fill up the data in perticular textbox using javascript dynamically.

on button click i got response like this `{"id":67,"value":"venue 1","Xvalue":"venue 1"}`

i tried to :  `$('#venue_name').val(msg.value);`

but instead of `#venue_name` I want to use the `closest()`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Look for `model-opened` event and then assign the value..

Comment: You will get the textbox element generated only after your model is open, so as mentioned in the comment above, look for the `model-opened` event, grab the textbox with an accessor and assign the value to it...

Comment: Use `$('.venue_name')` instead of `$('#venue_name')` as `value_name` is class name instead of id

Comment: But i have multiple modal in single page and set value of textbox dynamically so its not solution use class instead of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to set the value in the input box of model from the message.

You need to use the `shown.bs.modal` event of the modal.

```
var msg = {"id":67,"value":"venue 1","Xvalue":"venue 1"};

$('#edit-venue').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $("#venue").val(msg.value);
})
```

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/01zrxq7y/1/

Boostrap Doc : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: I have multiple modal on single page so how can I manage multiple modal textbox ?

Here, you used Form id for perticular form but multiple form how can manage ?

Comment: @keyz.Mist Can you update my JSFIDDLE and show me how your HTML is going to be and I'll be able to help you.

Comment: can you please help me ? I updated you JSFIDDLE.
modify in html and javascript.